# How to AutoFilter with Dates?

Tags: excel, vba

What is wrong here

```
Dim dt1 As Date
dt1 = DateSerial(2012, 9, 1)
r0.Columns(6).AutoFilter
r0.Columns(6).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=dt1, VisibleDropDown:=False
```

r0 is a range - 9 columns and 1300 rows
r0.Columns(6) has date format
Lot of cells in column 6 have value 1.9.2012 (visible in formula bar)
The result is as no one cell has this value. All rows in r0 are collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
r0.Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, Format(dt1, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Also, make sure the data in column 6 is `DateSerial` and not strings that *look* like dates.

Comment: chris, your code works, but why Criteria2, wihtout Criteria1 ? And how can I avoid the filter icon which appears in the header cell ?

Comment: @Alegro Filtering Dates is quite a bit more complex than other filters.  Best way to learn is to use the macro recorder while applying various filters.  Study the results and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Ok, everyThing works now. ThankYou. You are really a greatSolver.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it with this code:

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim dt1 As Date
  dt1 = DateSerial(2012, 9, 1)
  Dim r0 As Range
  Set r0 = Tabelle1.Range("A1:C23")
  'r0.Columns(3).AutoFilter
  r0.Columns(3).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=dt1, VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

On this data:

```
HeaderA | HeaderB| HeaderC
stuff   | stuff  | 01.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 01.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 02.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 04.04.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 01.02.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 07.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 01.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 08.10.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 01.09.2012
stuff   | stuff  | 01.09.2012
```

Worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Jook, but is it possible to do the same thing with a plain range, without creating a table ? I'm filtering r0 with my codes without problems if criteria is a string.

Comment: `with a plain range, without creating a table` ?!? when you don't have problem if criteria is a string, think about, what chris said. My dates were not strings, they were dates, which are represented by a number not a string, there is a big difference.